# Pass data submitted by Zend_Form in the view to the model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have created a form using zend form, which is in the form directory in the applications directory. I have created an instance of this form in the controller:

```
public function getBookSlotForm(){
        return new Application_Form_BookSlot();
    }
public function bookSlotAction()
    {
    $form = $this->getBookSlotForm();
    $this->view->form = $form;
    }
```

And displayed it to the user in the view:

```
echo $this->form;
```

When the user fills in the form, how do I do I store that data in variables in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim is correct as far as he goes, but you seem like you need a little more detail. you seem to have no issue with getting your form displayed on the page. Now to get the data from that form into your controller and then on to any model you want is pretty simple an straight forward.

I'm going to assume you are using the post method in your form for this example.

When you post your form in any php application it will send it's data in an array form to the `$_POST` variable. In ZF this variable is stored in the frontcontroller in the request object and is accessed usually with `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` and will return an associated array of values:

```
//for example $this->getRequest->getPost();
POST array(2) {
  ["query"] => string(4) "joel"
  ["search"] => string(23) "Search Music Collection"
}

//for example $this->getRequest()->getParams();
PARAMS array(5) {
  ["module"] => string(5) "music"
  ["controller"] => string(5) "index"
  ["action"] => string(7) "display"
  ["query"] => string(4) "joel"
  ["search"] => string(23) "Search Music Collection"
}
```

as a special case when using forms that extend `Zend_Form` you should access your form values using `$form->getValues()` as this will return form values that have had the form filters applied, `getPost()` and `getParams()` will not apply the form filters.

So now that we know what we are receiving from the process of sending the values to the model is pretty simple:

```
public function bookSlotAction()
{
    $form = $this->getBookSlotForm();
    //make sure the form has posted
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
      //make sure the $_POST data passes validation
      if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
         //get filtered and validated form values
         $data = $form->getValues();
         //instantiate your model
         $model = yourModel();
         //use data to work with model as required
         $model->sendData($data);
      }
      //if form is not vaild populate form for resubmission
      $form->populate($this->getRequest()->getPost());
   }
   //if form has been posted the form will be displayed
   $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical workflow is:

```
public function bookSlotAction()
{
    $form = $this->getBookSlotForm();
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
        // do stuff and then redirect
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

calling isValid() will also store the data in the form object, so if validation fails, your form will be redisplayed with the data the user entered filled in.